# DataTable Performance - Repeated Append or Multiple Update?

Tags: c#, datatable

Using C#, Framework 4.6.1 console app performs some work filling a DataTable after reading a file from local disk and serializing output to local disk. Console app will run in parallel ~ 32 instances at a time. No DB access. Single thread in the console app.

The DataTable always starts with 12 columns, 0 rows and will grow to 3,000-9,000 DataRows. I am trying to understand from a memory and DataTable-filling-speed perspective if it makes more sense to create the DataTable at the given size (filing all rows with null) and then update the rows as needed (in update sets of 1-64), or create new DataRows (up to 64 at a time) and append them to the DataTable sequentially.

Thanks.

Comment: If there is no DB involved don't use a DataTable. DataTables are heavy and slow. If your data is well known use POCOs and e.g. List<T>. That will give you the smallest memory footprint and will be quickest. You can still query that later with LINQ to Objects

Comment: @FrankJ, DataTables are the best construct for this system: the data incoming is not well known, the serialization story is good for DTs, and relative heaviness/slowness to POCOs is not a concern for this system. I do need a deeper understanding of DataTable in this instance however.

Comment: In this case your best bet is probably to write a little program that processes bogus data and try it both ways and profile to measure the differences. Sorry, that I can't help you more. When we looked into DTs it kept up to 3 copies of the data and was balooning in memory footprint and was also very slow - so if I would have to guess filling it once is quicker, but without measuring I wouldn't trust this guess.